# mouse co ordinates using event.pageX returns undefined

Tags: jquery

In jQuery i tried

```
$(".bydd").live("change", function (event) {
    // all other actions are happening
    console.log(event.pageX);

});
```

when i checked console it is `undefined`. I also tried `window.X`

Comment: what jquery version you used?

Comment: the version is 1.7.2

Comment: can you show `.bydd`?

Comment: you are expecting `pageX` in a `change` event, wel it won't be there

Comment: @skip405 what function should i use?

Comment: `live` deprecated use `.on` above 1.7.2

Comment: @vignesh, that depends on what you are trying to achieve. A fiddle would help to understand where you are going

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.. live method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.  you can use a mousemove handler that just stores the information

```
<script>
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
});
</script>
```

Please refere below link for the reference.

[Differences Between jQuery .bind() vs .live() vs .delegate() vs .on()
Introduction](http://www.elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/)

Comment: mouse co ordinates using event.pageX returns undefined. I think he need this only.

Comment: yes you are right . add some explanation about your code .. you only explain about `live` event .  you should explain about `mousemove ` event also

Comment: Ohh thats true. Let me add some explaination.

Comment: So you are just closing your eyes that the coordinates are needed on `.bydd` value `change`, right? The correct way is to simply throw that thing away and change to `document.mousemove` ))

Answer (score 0):

The code will not work on change event ... I have created a simple demo of the same

```js
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```